# Spring Data JPA Class Projection Without Constructor

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I can have a interface projection like this:

```
public interface Person {
  String getFirstName();
  String getLastName();
}
```

And I can have JPQL query in a `JpaRepository` like this:

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

  @Query("select e.firstName as firstName, e.lastName as lastName from Employee e")
  List<Person> fetchEmployeeNames();
}
```

The class projection equivalent would look like this:

```
public class Person {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;

  public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }

  // getters and setters
}
```

With the JPQL using the constructor like this:

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

  @Query("select new my.package.Person(e.firstName, e.lastName) from Employee e")
  List<Person> fetchEmployeeNames();
}
```

Using the interface projection query with a class projection would result in this exception:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [my.package.Person]
```

Why can't I use class projection without specifying the constructor, exactly like the interface JPQL? Is there anyway to allow class projection without specifying the constructor? Can I create a generic converter to convert to any class projection?

Comment: Just write in repository `List<Person> findBy();` I think this will do what you want

Comment: Hmm, but what if I want where conditions or joins or other things in the query? I want to keep using JPQL for complicated queries

Comment: You can use [Query creation from method names](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) for where conditions

Comment: I could do that, but that will end up with very long method names, and it's only for where conditions. what about joins and group by and function calls, etc?

Comment: If you have too much complex query it's better to  use the constructor with class or interface.

Comment: Well yeah, that's what I'm trying to do. I just want to use class projection without constructors.

Comment: But I don't understand why this is required? I don't think it's possible as per design

Comment: It's not required. It's just easier to use without constructor. What if I want to exclude some fields? I'd have to set param to null or create a new constructor. What if I forget the param ordering? I'd have to look it up. If I have like 10 fields it's hard to see what param it's set to. It's the same reason named parameters are easier to use over referencing by index.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying is not possible. If you need custom WHERE conditions you could implement this by making use of the `findAll(Specification<Employee> s)` method through default methods in interfaces.